# How to restore db table from models in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I had two models(Reporter and Article). I did

```
makemigrations 
migrate
```

it created two tables in the database. Then I accidentally dropped the tables from the database.

Now, when I do migrate again, it says that the table does not exist. It does not create tables from models. The error message is:

```
relation "first_test_article" does not exist
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You want to restore data or recreate db from scratch?

Comment: @coldmind I want to restore my two tables. appname_reporter and appname_article

Comment: Your last migration is that creates these tables?
The problem is that if you will migrate backwards to previous, exception will probably raise, because it will be trying to delete inexistent tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your last migration is that creates these tables?

The problem is that if you will migrate backwards to previous, exception will probably raise, because it will be trying to delete inexistent tables.

The way you can solve it is to create these tables (empty, without fields) by hands, then you should migrate backwards to previous migration. It will delete these tables, and then you will be able to migrate forwards and create these tables again.